# Rate of heat loss from a water tank

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I'm doing a project for which I need to calculate heat dissipation from a water tank. I'm not well versed in thermodynamics and I can't find any place where this has been answered.

I don't know the exact dimensions of the tank I'll be performing this on so I assumed a dimension of $2m \times 1m \times 1m$ and it has a capacity of 2000 litres of water. For a first estimate, I assumed wall thicknesses to be zero and used Newton's law of cooling, essentially turning it into a floating cuboid shaped blob of water with the transfer coefficient of concrete and the surface area is all six faces of the cuboid ( I don't know if this is even remotely reasonable).

Heat Transfer coeff $= h=12 \mathrm{W/(kg.K)}$
Surface Area $= A=10 \mathrm{m^2}$
Mass $= m=2000 \mathrm{kg}$
Volume $= V=2 \mathrm{m^3}$

I used the equation:
$$ T(t)=T_{env} +(T(0)-T_{env})e^{-t/\tau}$$

where
$$ \tau=\frac{mc}{hA}=\frac{2000\times 4200}{12\times 10}=70000$$
$$T_{env}=281K$$
$$T_0=298K$$

making the equation
$$T(t)=281 +(298-281)e^{-t/70000}$$

and heat loss equation is;

$$\frac{dU}{dt}=C\frac{dT}{dt}= (4200\times2000)\times\frac{17\times e^{-t/70000}}{70000}$$

where $C$ is heat capacity.

Would this equation be a reasonable assumption? Are there any other factors I should take into account?
Also is there any analytical solution for Newton's cooling law in Two layered systems or something, if so where can I find it?